# Categorical variable in Python/Scikitlearn without one-hot encoding

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, categorical-data

Is it possible to use a categorical variable, as-is, in Python/Scikit-learn GLM models? I do realize the alternative of one-hot encoding. My issue with this approach is that I will be unable to test the entire variable for significance. I can only test the encoded variable (which is partial).

Why is it that SAS can handle such a variable and not Python? Please advise.

Comment: Ultimately you need to understand what SAS is doing "under the hood"  Computers deal with numerical values, not "categories"

Answer (score 2):

It actually depends on the data that you have. For instance, if you can assign some sort of order to the categorical variable (Ordinal Values) like `low`,`medium` and `high`, you can assign them numbers like 1, 2 and 3. However, it gets a little trickier if there is no order whatsoever. Besides One-hot Encoding, you can try [Helmert Coding Scheme](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/helmert.html). You can also read [this blog post](http://www.kdnuggets.com/2015/12/beyond-one-hot-exploration-categorical-variables.html) for more analysis. There are also various other coding schemes in sklearn for categorical variables:

- [Sum Coding](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/sum.html)
- [Polynomial Coding](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/polynomial.html)
- [Backward Difference Coding](http://httphttp://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/backward_difference.html)

You can read more about other [Categorical Encoders in Sklearn here](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/index.html?highlight=encoders).